# What is the outcome for Dors Venabili?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

In the Isaac Asimov book *Forward the Foundation* I'm curious about the future of Dors Venabili:

> She dies in the arms of Hari Seldon after being exposed to an enhanced version of the Elar Monai device.
>
>  I would like to know if this is the definite end of Dors, or if she ever gets repaired by Daneel and gets back to her family. If not, is there any reason why she doesn't get fixed in the rest of the books?

Comment: You will have to read the *Triumph of the Foundation* trilogy to answer this one.

Comment: I see. There's hope. Thank you @b_jonas

Comment: And as for why she doesn't get fixed in any of Asimov's books, http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book502.html claims that Dors's character in *Forward the Foundation* is based on Asimov's experience with her first wife Janet, who died in real life.

Comment: @b_jonas: Janet was Asimov's second wife, and she is still alive.

Comment: @Ubik [She](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janet_Asimov) died a month after your comment, and 26 years after Asimov